# If $f(u(x), v(y))=f(x, y)$, can we conclude that either $u(x)=x$ or $v(y)=y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $f\in k[x, y]$ is
>   an irreducible polynomial in two variables. Furthermore, suppose that $f(u(x),
> v(y))=f(x, y)$ for every $x, y\in k$, where $u\in k[x]$, $v\in k[y]$ are
>   polynomials of one variable. Can we conclude that either $u(x)=x$ or
>   $v(y)=y$?

I think the answer is "yes". I am thinking maybe we can use some sort of degree argument, but there could be some cancellations if we try to expand $f(u(x), v(y))$.

This question naturally arose to me when I was reading Section 1.4 "Rational Maps" in *Basic Algebraic Geometry* by Shafarevich. But, as far as I can tell, it is not directly related to any of the results presented there.

Comment: A really trivial counterexample is when $f$ is constant (maybe that's not "irreducible"). Or $f(x,y)=x+y$, and while $u$ adds a constant, $v$ subtracts the same constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Take $f(x,y)=x^2-1+y^2$ and $u(x)=-x,$ $\nu(y)=-y.$ If you want some more "nontrivial" examples, you can consider symmetries with respect to $x\to 1-x$ or something like that (instead of obvious one $x\to -x.$)

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the swift answer.

Comment: On the other hand, the degree argument _should_ go through to show that $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ must be linear...

Answer (score 3):

You can have $f(x,y)=x+y$, and then $u$ can shift by a constant, with $v$ shifting in reverse.